# The best way to create animation diagram

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create something like this: 
[image]

I looked many resources for that, but I still don't  have idea how can I do it. Using CoreAnimation, Quartz2d or UIBezierPath I can draw a circle,  but how can I draw a nice diagram with touch gesture's aid, using that? Maybe I wrong searched? If any tutorial, or sample code for this issue?

Comment: Please check my answer below. and you may ask for further help in using this library. Thanks

Comment: pie chart  looks really nice! Thank you! You was right, I'm a little puzzled ) I add needed files files to my project, but how can I add diagram to viewController?

Comment: You will add UIView in your ViewController and BasicPieChart Object and implement its delegates.

Comment: For Further code help you may add me to skype: amir.ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best and easy library I used to draw pie chart with animation; MIM Chart Library for iOS

https://github.com/ReetuRaj/MIMChart-Library

Open source.

Answer (score 0):

OK, CoreAnimation is not what you're looking for with this.

Anyway...

If you want to make a nice Pie Chart then you should take a look at [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot).

It has a lot of graphing functions and pie charts are in there too.

You can still animate with this you just need to update the percentages based on touch. Don't try to animate the sections of the circle. Change the percentages and update the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do some charts & plotting. If that is so, there is something called as

1. [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot)
2. [ILGraphics](https://github.com/eul/ILGraphics)
3. [OVGraphView](https://github.com/owenv/OVGraphView)
4. [Some controls as well](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graphs)

   Hope that helps.